# Php error, Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active

Tags: php

People report having this issue on a website of mine. But the code goes like:

```
    $class = get_called_class();
    $instance = new \ReflectionClass($class);

    $class::$List = array_flip($instance->getConstants()); // Error here
```

I absolutely never get that error myself.

Does somebody know what's happening?

Comment: what is the exact error? you should log errors then you don't have to be able to reproduce it your self

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in...

Comment: Could we by any chance see the code / class where  `$class = get_called_class(); `is used?

Comment: What is `getConstants()`?

Comment: @JamesSpence, google PHP reflection

Comment: @davidkonrad Woops I just took a second look and saw that was an instance of ReflectionClass. I wasn't looking closely enough the first time, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

`get_called_class()` must be called inside the class itself. I guess you are not seeing errors because you have `error_reporting(0)` or similar on your localhost.

```php
class Test {
    static public function test() {
        echo get_called_class(); //OK
    }
}
```

not

```js
<?
echo get_called_class(); //Not OK
?>
```

---

**Update**. Eureka!

```php
$class = get_called_class();
$instance = new \ReflectionClass($class);
$class::$List = array_flip($instance->getConstants()); // Error here
```

should be

```php
...
$instance::List = array_flip($instance->getConstants());
```

You are trying to set a static non-existing value on a string. `get_called_class()` return a string, not an object, and certainly not a `static class`.

Comment: I'm calling get_called_class() from a class.

Comment: So post the code you are actually using so we can see that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears getConstants is broken on some version of PHP 5.3.x.